# truffle deploy --network ropsten issues

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

I am having an issue deploying to ropsten. I am receiving an insufficient funds error but I believe my address to have ether on ropsten.

This command:

```
truffle migrations --network ropsten
```

Also Tried:
    truffle deploy --network ropsten

Note, the next commands deploy successfully:
    truffle deploy --network development
    truffle migrations --network mainnet

config:

```
'use strict';

const keys = require("./private.js");
let privateKeyMain = keys.main;
let privateKeyRopsten = keys.test
let mainApiKey = keys.mainApiKey
let ropstenApiKey = keys.ropstenApiKey
let mnemonic = keys.mnemonic
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");


require('dotenv').config();
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3();
const WalletProvider = require("truffle-wallet-provider");
const Wallet = require('ethereumjs-wallet');

/*
var mainNetPrivateKey = new Buffer(privateKeyMain, "hex")
var mainNetWallet = Wallet.fromPrivateKey(mainNetPrivateKey);
// var mainNetProvider = new WalletProvider(mainNetWallet, "mainnet.infura.io/v3/" + mainApiKey);

var ropstenPrivateKey = new Buffer(privateKeyRopsten, "hex")
var ropstenWallet = Wallet.fromPrivateKey(ropstenPrivateKey);
*/

var mainNetProvider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/" + mainApiKey);
// var ropstenProvider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/" + ropstenApiKey);
var ropstenProvider = new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "ropsten.infura.io/v3/cb06dad7697b45b3999d15a8745be75c" + ropstenApiKey);/*
development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*"
    },
mainnet: {
  provider: mainNetProvider,
  gas: 4600000,
  gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei("20", "gwei"),
  network_id: "1",
}
*/
module.exports = {
  networks: {

    ropsten: {
      provider: ropstenProvider,
      // You can get the current gasLimit by running
      // truffle deploy --network rinkeby
      // truffle(rinkeby)> web3.eth.getBlock("pending", (error, result) =>
      //   console.log(result.gasLimit))
      gas: 4600000,
      gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei("20", "gwei"),
      network_id: "4",
    },

  },

  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.5.0",
    }
  },

  solc: {
    optimizer: {
      enabled: true,
      runs: 1
    }
  },

  mocha: {
    reporter: 'eth-gas-reporter',
    reporterOptions: {
      currency: 'USD',
      gasPrice: 10
    }
  }
};
```

My error

Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"Migrations" could not deploy due to insufficient funds
   * Account:  0x1a3681a9f7A10210Ed71E867821543CC8c85c71b
   * Balance:  0 wei
   * Message:  insufficient funds for gas * price + value
   * Try:
      + Using an adequately funded account
      + If you are using a local Geth node, verify that your node is synced.

```
at /Users/jakemartin/.nvm/versions/node/v10.9.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-deployer/src/deployment.js:364:1
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Truffle v5.0.5 (core: 5.0.5)
Node v10.9.0

It occurs during the deployment of migrations.

But if you look up that address at ropsten.etherscan, it has funds. Check for yourself! https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x1a3681a9f7a10210ed71e867821543cc8c85c71b

I'm stuck - advice appreciated

**----UPDATE-----**

Now it just hangs...

Only things I changed are gasPrice and gas.

New ropsten config:

```
 ropsten: {
    provider: ropstenProvider,
    // You can get the current gasLimit by running
    // truffle deploy --network rinkeby
    // truffle(rinkeby)> web3.eth.getBlock("pending", (error, result) =>
    //   console.log(result.gasLimit))
    gas: 6500000,
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toWei("400", "gwei"),
    network_id: "4",
  }
```

Comment: Now it just hangs...

Only things I changed are gasPrice and gas.

Answer (score 1):

> Your given `network_id` in `networks:` was wrong. It should be
>   `network_id :"3"` if you are connecting with ropsten. `network_id :"4"` present rinkeby testnet.